# $f$: differentiable on $\Bbb R$ & $ \vert f'(x) \vert <1$ all $x$, $f(0)=0$, then $\vert f(x) \vert < \vert x \vert$ ,all $x \in \Bbb R$($x \ne 0$)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I think $\vert f(x) \vert / \vert x \vert < 1$ and use a limit $x \to 0$ or mean value theorem 
But i can't hang of it
Elaborate please: )

Comment: Use mean value theorem instead

Comment: I edited your post to make the $\LaTeX$ pretty.  I also deleted your tag "differential-forms", since the accepted usage of that term describes something different.  Then I added the "real-analysis" and "derivatives" tags.  Cheers!

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Applying Mean Value Theorem to the function $f$ on the interval $[0,x]$ or $[x,0]$one get that there is $c\in (0,x)$ or $(x,0)$ such that $$f(x)-f(0)=f'(t)(x-0).$$

¿Can you continue..?

Answer (score 0):

Since $f:  \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is differentiable, it is also continuous.  Thus for any $0 < x \in \Bbb R$, $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0, x]$ and differentiable on $(0, x)$; thus the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) may be applied to affirm that there exists some $\xi \in (0, x)$ with

$f(x) = f(x) - f(0) = f'(\xi)(x - 0) = f'(\xi)x; \tag 1$

thus,

$\vert f(x) \vert = \vert f'(\xi) x \vert = \vert f'(\xi) \vert \vert x \vert < \vert x \vert \tag 2$

since

$\vert f'(\xi) \vert < 1.\tag 3$

In the event that $\Bbb R \ni x < 0$, we apply the same argument over the interval $[x, 0]$:

$-f(x) = f(0) - f(x) = f'(\xi)(0 - x) = -f'(\xi)x, \tag 4$

and then

$f(x) = f'(\xi) x, \tag 5$

from which (2) follows once again.